# Set position relative to scene in Cocos2d

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to use a `DrawNode` in cocos2d which is a child of a `Sprite`. The `Sprite`'s position and rotation influences the child `DrawNode`'s position and rotation as you would expect.

I'm trying to set the `DrawNode`'s position and rotation to be not affected by it's parent (the `Sprite`).

I've tried changing `self->addChild(self->drawNode)` to `self->getScene()->addChild(self->drawNode)` which would work perfectly (if it worked), but I receive an error saying `self->getScene()` returns a `nullptr`. And this happens because it has not yet been added to any scene.

How can I position the `DrawNode` relative to the scene/world?

For example:

`this->drawNode()->drawLine(Point::ZERO, Point(0, 100), Color4F::RED)`
draw's a line going straight up from the sprite.

I am aiming for it to draw a line straight  up from the bottom right of the window.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yeah I understand that's a possibility, but I'm just trying to keep my code clean and minimize the scene class if that makes sense. It would just be a lot better if I could keep the `DrawNode` as a child of the player `Sprite`

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thank you for the lovely edit you made to my question

Comment: @Rabbid76 why do you keep making unchanged edits to my question?

Comment: @Rabbid76 to remove your downvote?

Comment: @Rabbid76 you can't just undo the down vote by untoggling the down vote button, or even upvoting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the scene before adding the sprite to it, the current running scene can always be accessed from the director.

```
auto scene = Director::getInstance()->getRunningScene();
scene->addChild(draw_node);
```